# Not able to Debug my plugin in petrel 2013

Tags: ocean, petrel

When i am trying to debug my plugin following error shows after few seconds "a debugger is attached and debugging of petrel startup is not supported. Please Detach the Debugger". Please help me resolving this  issue

Answer (score 4):

What is the reason you want to start Petrel from a VS with an attached debugger?

1) If you want to be able to use the VS "Edit and Continue" feature, your only option is the 32-bit developer's build of Petrel (you will need an Ocean license).

2) If you are trying to debug your plug-in initialization, you could add the following statement to the code you want to debug

```
#if DEBUG
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif
```

This will attach a debugger if you are running a debug build of your plug-in

DR

Answer (score 2):

this is expected behavior when you're running a x64-bit version of Petrel. You've two choices; 1) get a 32-bit version of Petrel, or 2) create a msgbox in your plug-in and attach VS to the petrel.exe process when it pops up.

Comment: You may also go to **DEBUG -> Attach to process...** and select Petrel.exe once Petrel has loaded.